# Mixed criticality system based on Ubuntu

Tags: realtime

**Is there a way to implement a mixed criticality system based on Ubuntu?** I.e. if we have some software module that is complex and non-critical and we want to develop it as usual on Ubuntu. And we have some code that requires real-time constraints. Can we run it on single machine under linux? E.g. dedicate a core for real-time task, shield it from all the interrupts, be sure that system calls and periphery queries will respond in a certain time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is something Ubuntu-specific. The tool for that is cgroups of the Linux kernel.

Try and see if it is enough.